# Complex variable integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves, complex-integration

**Question:** Consider $\gamma_1 = [z_0 - r, z_0 + r]$ and $\gamma_2: [0, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma_2(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$. Let $z \notin \gamma_1^* \cup \gamma_2^*$.
Evaluate
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1 * \gamma_2} \frac{1}{(w - z)} \, dw.
$

I have some doubts in this solution,

**Solution:**

If $|z| > 1$, then we are done. So assume that $z$ lies strictly inside the upper-semicircle.

Let $\gamma_3 : [\pi, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $\gamma_3(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$. Then clearly,
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1 * \gamma_2} \frac{dw}{(w - z)} \, + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_3 * \tilde{\gamma}_1
} \frac{dw}{(w - z)}$

$
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{dw}{(w - z)} \, dw + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_3} \frac{dw}{(w - z)} \
$

$
 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(0;1)} \frac{dw}{(w - z)}
$

= 1.

Since $z$ lies in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus (\gamma_3 * \tilde{\gamma}_1)^*$, so $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_3 * \tilde{\gamma}_1} \frac{1}{(w - z)^2} \, dw = 0$. Hence,
$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1 * \gamma_2} \frac{dw}{(w - z)} = 1.
$

Where $\int_{\gamma_1 * \gamma_3} = \int_{\gamma_1} + \int_{\gamma_3}$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ is the opposite path of $\gamma$

I could not understand the above solution like

What is happening when $|z| > 1$ ?

Why is $\gamma_3$ being constructed in such a way?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate), the complex conjugate of $z$ is sometimes written as $z^{*}$. I don't know what it means to take the "*" of two sets in $\mathbb{C}$ or what the ~ symbol means, even after doing a bit of Googling.